# How to display list of users connected to PostgreSQL server

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to display list of users connected to PostgreSQL server.
When I ran the query:

```
select client_hostname from pg_stat_activity
```

it's returning the hostname in following format:

```
machine_name.domain_name.com
```

I just wanted to confirm will it always return `client_hostname` in the mentioned format? Or it may vary from domain to domain?
How does PostgreSQL create the string `domain_name.com`?
If I want to create the same string via java application, how can I create it?

Answer (score 4):

I think your version is PostgreSQL 9.1 or later. The [**manual**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) says about the `client_hostname` field:

> Host name of the connected client, as reported by a reverse DNS lookup
>   of `client_addr`. This field will only be non-null for IP connections,
>   and only when log_hostname is enabled.

So `client_hostname` filed will not always display not null information. And I suggest you use a superuser to query the `pg_stat_activity` view.

Comment: how about getting history of this? what connections have been made the wast week or so?

Comment: yes, if you set the log_connections parameters in postgresql.conf, you can get history in your csv database logs.